# Update a react components state from its parent

Tags: reactjs

Is it ok to update React components state by calling its member function from its parent. Something like:

```
class SomeComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  } 

  updateState(data) {
    this.setState({ data: data })
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>this.state.data</div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full class just to make sure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it ok to update React components state by calling its member function from controller?

Yes, you *can* do that but it's unnecessary. Usually you want to update the child state by passing down props from the parent. I've made some examples of how you can update a Child from the Parent below.

---

### Example 1:

In this example, you don't need any state for the Child. The Parent manages the state and passes down any changes to the Child via props. This is the recommended approach.

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {text: "hello"};
  } 

  render() {
    return <Child data={this.state.text} />;
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return <span>{this.props.data}</span>;
  }
}
```

---

### Example 2:

In this example, we use two states, one for each component. This is unnecessary for this implementation, but you can still do it. When the Child mounts, we set the state to whatever the data prop is set to. We update the state whenever the Child component receives props with `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {text: "hello"};
  } 

  render() {
    return <Child data={this.state.text} />;
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {childText: props.data};
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.data !== this.props.data)
      this.setState({childText: data});
  }

  render() {
    return <span>{this.state.childText}</span>;
  }
}
```

---

### Example 3:

In this example, the Child component is given a `ref` which we then can use to trigger a Child function from Parent. Usually this is done in the reverse order (triggering a function from Child to Parent), but you can still do this if you want. This is the more manual approach and similar to what you asked.

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {text: "hello"};
  }

  triggerUpdate = () => {
    this.child.component.update(this.state.text);
  }

  render() {
    return <Child ref={(el) => this.child = el} data={this.state.text} />;
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {childText: props.data};
  }

  update = (text) => {
    this.state({childText: text});
  }
    
  render() {
    return <span>{this.state.childText}</span>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi should it be `this.props.children[0]` instead of `this.child`?

Comment: @Xin No. It's just an arbitrary name I chose for that component's reference name. Nothing to do with React props or state per se.