# How to update the state of a sibling component from another sibling or imported component in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i just recently started learning ReactJS and been playing around the import and export functions, For example this is the structure of the app, 3 separate files the parent and 2 children; How do i export the state from InputArea to DisplayArea?

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DisplayArea from './DisplayArea';
import InputArea from './InputArea';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="wrapper" className="App">
        <DisplayArea />
        <InputArea />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Child 1 Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InputArea from './InputArea';

class DisplayArea extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="column">
            <div className="col-body">
                <div id="preview">{ How to display contents here? }</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default DisplayArea;
```

**Child 2 Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class InputArea extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        content: ''
      }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        content: e.target.value
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="column">

            <div className="col-body">
                <textarea id="editor" placeholder="Enter text here" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default InputArea;
```

Comment: This is a fundemental concept with react. Passing props is a one way street unless you use some sort of state management like Redux. I already anwsered this here ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858242/dealing-with-nested-react-components-state-changes/47858356#47858356

You should try to avoid using props from one children to another lateral like you are doing, Either next the third child in the second, or use state management. 

Regardless of your choice you will need to create a 'updateParent' function that you can find in my previous answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in your situation. The second option is what @Gavin Thomas suggested in the comment. But without Redux you can do it like:

```js
const InputArea = (props) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => props.handleInputValue(e.target.value);

  return (
    <div className="column">
      <div className="col-body">
        <textarea
          id="editor"
          placeholder="Enter text here"
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const DisplayArea = (props) => (
  <div className="column">
    <div className="col-body">
      <div id="preview">{props.inputValue}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: "Initial Value",
  };

  handleInputValue = (inputValue) => this.setState({ inputValue });

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="wrapper" className="App">
        <DisplayArea inputValue={this.state.inputValue} />
        <InputArea handleInputValue={this.handleInputValue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here, we hold our input value state in the parent component, which is App. We pass a callback function to InputArea and change our parent component's state using this callback function. Then we pass this state to our DisplayArea component.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, definitely go for Redux after digesting React.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the relevant parts of the code. Basically passing a `liftState` method to the `InputArea` component which will actually update the state of `App` when called. Then pass `content` to `DisplayArea` as a prop.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content: ""
        };
    }
    liftState = state => {
        this.setState(state);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <InputArea liftState={this.liftState}/>
                <DisplayArea content={this.state.content}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class InputArea extends Component {
    handleChange(event) {
        this.props.liftState({content: event.target.value});
    }
}

class DisplayArea extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="column">
                <div className="col-body">
                    <div id="preview">{this.props.content}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The React.js documentation says ([Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)):

> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We
>   recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common
>   ancestor...

Example:

```
// Parent component which contains shared state
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      child1Value: 0,
      child2Value: 0,
    }

    this.handleChild1Click = this.handleChild1Click.bind(this);
    this.handleChild2Click = this.handleChild2Click.bind(this);
  }

  handleChild1Click(nextValue) {
    this.setState({ child1Value: nextValue });
  }

  handleChild2Click(nextValue) {
    this.setState({ child2Value: nextValue });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          value={this.state.child2Value}
          onClick={this.handleChild1Click}
        />
        <Child
          value={this.state.child1Value}
          onClick={this.handleChild2Click}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.value + 1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Value of my sibling: {this.props.value}</p>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}></button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is cool and correct, but I think everyone would appreciate some code!

Comment: @JimmyAdaro I've provided an example. I hope it becomes more clear for you. Consider to use a new approach of sharing state between components - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html