# React - Can you update an Unstated container state from an external function?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, unstated

In the example from the Unstated library they update state within a container by interacting with a jsx button that is subscribed to the container.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider, Subscribe, Container } from 'unstated';

type CounterState = {
  count: number
};

class CounterContainer extends Container<CounterState> {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  increment() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  decrement() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
  }
}

function Counter() {
  return (
    <Subscribe to={[CounterContainer]}>
      {counter => (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => counter.decrement()}>-</button>
          <span>{counter.state.count}</span>
          <button onClick={() => counter.increment()}>+</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </Subscribe>
  );
}

render(
  <Provider>
    <Counter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Is there a way to update the state within the container from a function in a component outside of the Container? So for instance if I want up to update state during the return of a promise how would I go about doing so. Pseudo code

```
login = () => {
    let url = baseURL + '/user/login?_format=json';  

    let data = {
      "name": this.state.email,  
      "pass": this.state.password
    };



        axios({
          url,
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept':  'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          withCredentials: true,
          credentials: 'same-origin', 
          data,
          })
          .then(function(result) {
            console.log('result:', result);
                SET STATE HERE!!!!!!!
counter.increment()

              })
          .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
      };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't specific to Unstated, this would apply to React context API that uses render prop pattern, too.

The problem with `login` is that its control flow is flawed. It isn't be able to efficiently catch errors because it suppresses them. And it encapsulates the promise inside, which is a mistake that prevents it from being properly tested, for starters

It can expose a promise, or accept a callback, or both:

```
login = async (cb) => {
  ...    
  return axios(...)
  .then(function(result) {
    if (cb)
      cb(result);

    return result;
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
}
```

Can be used as:

```
<button onClick={() => login(() => counter.decrement())}>-</button>
```

Or:

```
<button onClick={async () => { await login(); counter.decrement(); }}>-</button>
```

It's also possible to make `login` accept `counter` as an argument but this would couple it to implementation which is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you @estus I ended up going with the inline async/await, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I see that you are including cb in here which I'm assuming is to represent callback. What would be the use case for a callback vs just returning the promise?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question, with many solutions to your problem. You need to pass the function to a child, that then updates the parent. I will link to a previous answer that I posted. In your case, where you render

```
<Login upParentCounter={this.increment}/>
```

And inside the login component

```
this.props.upParentCounter()
```

[Dealing with Nested React Components' State Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858242/dealing-with-nested-react-components-state-changes/47858356#47858356)