# Async/Await preventing second promise from executing

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, try-catch

Lets say I have  a login function

```
login = () => {
    let url = baseURL + '/user/login?_format=json';  

    let data = {
      "name": this.state.email,  
      "pass": this.state.password
    };


    return axios({
      url,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept':  'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'same-origin'
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log('result:', result);
        this.setState({csrfToken: result.data.csrf_token}); 
        this.setState({logoutToken: result.data.logout_token});
        return result;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
  };
```

I then want to call the function onSubmit in React like follows. If the function returns an error for any reason. How do I prevent the next function in this case `api.login()` from being run?

```
{api => (
            <Form
                onSubmit={async e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  await this.login();
                  api.login()
                }}
              >
    <input/>
    </Form>
```

Does a try/catch make sense in this case? I've tried several options including an inline try catch and the function runs no matter what happens as soon as the promise from `this.login();` returns either an result or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put `api.login()` inside the first login promise `then` callback?

```
login = () => {
let url = baseURL + '/user/login?_format=json';  

let data = {
  "name": this.state.email,  
  "pass": this.state.password
};


return axios({
  url,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept':  'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: 'same-origin'
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log('result:', result);
    this.setState({csrfToken: result.data.csrf_token}); 
    this.setState({logoutToken: result.data.logout_token});
    api.login() // <----- if you want to check result just wrap it in an if statement if (result) api.login()
    return result;
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
```

};

Otherwise you can make `login()` to return a boolean or a truthy/falsy value then do something like this (untested code):

```
{api => (
        <Form
            onSubmit={async e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              await this.login() && api.login()  
            }}
          >
<input/>
</Form>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your first suggestion?

Comment: also your untested code works perfectly... I'm just curious

Comment: *Why not put api.login() inside the first login promise then callback?* I suppose this was done because `api` is unavailable in `login` scope, and these two functions are decoupled.

Comment: yes true, but this was a question to encourage thought process for refactoring options

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem that is mentioned in [the answer to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52285225/3731501),

> The problem with login is that its control flow is flawed. It isn't be able to efficiently catch errors because it suppresses them.

`.catch(error => console.log('error:', error))` suppresses the error, while it shouldn't for proper control flow. Rejections should be handled at top level where a promise is consumed. Even if an error needs to be handled in `catch` (it's not necessary that `console.log` is needed at all), it should be rethrown.

Consistent handling of asynchronous errors is a separate concern in React. Asynchronous errors need to be caught and rethrown synchronously in lifecycle hooks (likely `componentDidUpdate`):

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state && this.state.error) {
      throw this.state.error;
    }
  }

  onSubmit = async e => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      await this.login();
      api.login();
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ error: err });
    }
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input/>
    </Form>
    ...
  }
```

The error that is rethrown in `componentDidUpdate` will propagate up to error boundary component or will result in exception, a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ztdbj8).

Some additional helpers may be introduced to DRY `try {...} catch (err) { this.setState({ error: err }) }` boilerplate up.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be happening because you're just running a console.log in your catch method, instead of throwing an error or rejecting a Promise. So the try/catch block for your await continues to run as if all is OK. Try throwing an error with Promise.reject or new Error().

```
var catchWithoutRejection = async () => {
  await console.log('hello')
  console.log('running')
}

catchWithoutRejection();

// hello
// running
// Promise {<resolved>: undefined}

var catchWithRejection = async () => {
  await Promise.reject("hello")
  console.log('not running')
}

catchWithRejection();
// Promise {<rejected>: "hello"}
```